# Open Source PHP script for HTTP video streaming?

Tags: php, video-streaming

Open Source PHP script for HTTP video streaming?

I need some PHP script or script lib for enabling reading and writing from and to a HTTP stream. I want to write chunks of data...

Actually I'm looking for such thing because adobe Flash 10.1 now supports it... So it looks for me lots of such questions will appear soon)

BTW: I do not need some special server - I need a script that will be using [PHP  Streams](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php)
Introduced in php 4.3 so it will work on normal apache php hosting…

So… What do I need? 
I need -

•  Open Source Libs

•  Tutorials

•  Blog posts/Articles

Comment: Community Wiki? I really think that, while possible under php, you will likely want/need to find a server component that is built specifically for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would something like [xmoov](http://xmoov.com/) work for you? it appears to have some means to allow you to get intimate with the video-stream, but I've not used it first hand