# How to make Video conference application in HTML 5? 

Tags: php, flash, html

How to make Video conference application in HTML 5? 
actually I want to build web conference application using HTML5. Please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** According to the link David posted as a comment. it is possible: http://whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#devices

unfortunetely it is not possible with html5 alone, you will need flash for three reasons:

1. HTML 5 can’t interact with a webcam.
2. HTML5 cannot record audio from your microphone.
3. HTML5 cannot do any sort of web conferencing.

source: http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/roundups/10-flash-things-you-can%E2%80%99t-do-with-html5/

cheers endo

Comment: As sources go, that one is pretty dreadful. I've done three of the things it claims are impossible. (And it has had had to repeat itself in an effort to look like it has 10 things)

Comment: youre right david, but facts are facts, no mic and no cam for html5-only-sites

Comment: I agree, facts are facts and endos answer is a good one to the question, but you could skip that source. The only good that came out of that article is probably that it inspired Bruce Lawson to this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0T13iiAzLM and this http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/roundups/html5-and-flash-17-industry-experts-have-their-say/#bruce_lawson

Comment: Mic and Cam are on the table for HTML: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#devices

Answer (score 5):

In mid 2012, things have changed quite a bit. [Webkit, Google Chrome and Opera support the getUserMedia API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream), and Google, Mozilla and Opera have partnered up to form the [WebRTC initiative](http://www.webrtc.org/). The initiative has the goald to *"enable rich, high quality, RTC applications to be developed in the browser via simple Javascript APIs and HTML5"*.

Check this [blog post of an HTML5 video conference demo](http://blog.bistri.com/post/26621841066/how-to-run-the-bistri-webrtc-demo-with-chrome), which was posted to the [discuss-webrtc Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/discuss-webrtc). The W3C is working on a specification [WebRTC 1.0: Real-time Communication Between Browsers](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html), the initial draft of the document was provided by Google.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a javascript API that you can use to connect to the webcam of devices http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html. That might be a start I guess.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 is wonderful, but I don't think it's the technology you're looking for.
If you want a barebones system, I would suggest a flash app that uploads a capture from the user's webcam to a server. Other users would do the same and to see each other would have to request the images from the server frequently. This probably wouldn't be a very good setup, though, and the frame rate would be awful.
You best bet would be with buying servers that are pre-programmed to support video streaming.
This question has already been asked a few times on stack overflow, so I'll point you in the direction of the already solved threads for the details:

- [Live Video Streaming with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223983/live-video-streaming-with-php)
- [How to do Http Video Streaming PHP or an referece site to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243919/how-to-do-http-video-streaming-php-or-an-referece-site-to-do-this)
- [Open Source PHP script for HTTP video streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766358/open-source-php-script-for-http-video-streaming)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the device element. This is not part of HTML5 yet, but will likely be in the next version of HTML. It is defined in the WhatWG spec, which is where HTML5 was originally defined when it was called Web Applications 1.0. See [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/commands.html#devices) for more information. Unfortunately I don't think this is supported in any browser yet, but it should be coming soon. There are already [experimental implementations](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-implementing-device-and-stream-management-webkit). Also see [the vision behind the device element](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-July/027129.html).

Otherwise for mobile there are already device APIs to access hardware and software features of the phone using HTML and JavaScript. Phones with these APIs should be coming to market in the not too distant future. See [Opera Labs](http://labs.opera.com/news/2010/12/22/) for more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

You might also check out some Open Source projects taht provide Video-Conferencing:

- http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/ (Using Adobe Flex)
- http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/ (Using OpenLaszlo)

OpenLaszlo can compile both Flash and DHTML. However as there is no webcam/micro support in DHTML yet, OpenMeetings is using the Flash plattform as client side technology.

Both projects are based on the Red5 Streaming Server.
Latest Apache OpenMeetings can be downloaded from: 
https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/OpenMeetings/job/OpenMeetings%202.0/